# Globally prevent hyphenation of word with underscore

Tags: hyphenation, underscore

I'm trying to prevent a word that contains an underscore to be hyphenated.

I have tried:

```
\hyphenation{Word\textunderscore With\textunderscore Underscore}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

Improper \hyphenation will be flushed.
\PD1-cmd ...\TextSymbolUnavailable #1}\fi \global 
                                                  \expandafter \let \csname ...
l.50  \hyphenation{Word\textunderscore
                                       With\textunderscore Underscore}
```

and

```
\usepackage{underscore}
\hyphenation{Word_With_Underscore}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

Improper \hyphenation will be flushed. l.50 \hyphenation{Word_
                       With_Underscore}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `underscore` does the opposite, it tries to allow hyphenation before and after the underscore. The macro `\BreakableUnderscore` can be redefined by
modifying the original definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{underscore}

\makeatletter
% Redefine to an unbreakable underscore
\renewcommand*{\BreakableUnderscore}{%
  \leavevmode
  \null % prevent hyphenation before the underscore
  % \nobreak
  % \hskip\z@skip
  \ifx\f@family\ttdefault
    \string_%
  \else
    \textunderscore
  \fi
  % \usc@dischyph\nobreak\hskip\z@skip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{%
  \hspace{0pt}document_document
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]